# Como meter una imagen en el option de un select javascript

Tags: javascript, select, img

Estoy intentando meter imágenes en el option de un select, no se si le tengo que aplicar algún tipo de css para que se muestre. Código queda así pero la imagen no se muestra.

```
<select id="Primero" name="Primero">
 <option value="0">Elige tu Primero</option>
 <option value="7" style="background-image:url(webroot\files\Platos\photo\gluten.png);">Macarrones</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39555/men%C3%BA-opciones-desplegable-con-im%C3%A1genes aquí se resuelve tu duda

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39555/men%C3%BA-opciones-desplegable-con-im%C3%A1genes aquí se resuelve esa duda.